# Linq casting in a Filter design

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I am trying to create a Specification class that I can pass to a Repository. That Specification has 2 parts, the Where clause (which works great) and the Filter which gives me an error any time you order by a property with type other than string.

```
    public class Specification<T> where T : class
    {
        public Expression<Func<T, bool>>? Where { get; init; }

        public Filter<T>? Filter { get; init; }
    }

    public class Filter<T> 
            where T : class
    {
        public IOrderBySelector<T>? OrderBy { get; init; }

        public IList<IOrderBySelector<T>> ThenBy { get; } = new List<IOrderBySelector<T>>();

        public bool Paginated { get; set; }

        public int ItemsPerPage { get; init; }

        public int CurrentPage { get; init; }
    }
```

I've isolated the cause of the error to the OrderSelector. The Filter converts the Selector Expression 'Expression<Func<T,TKey>>' to a LambdaExpression so that the caller can create any type of OrderBySelector they want. However, when you call the selector in a Linq query, it forgets the type of TKey and fails.

```
    public interface IOrderBySelector<T> where T : class
    {
        OrderByDirection Direction { get; }
        LambdaExpression? Selector { get; }
        Type? SelectorType { get; }
    }

    public class OrderBySelector<T, TKey> : IOrderBySelector<T>
        where T : class
        where TKey : notnull
    {

        public OrderByDirection Direction { get; init; }

        public Expression<Func<T, TKey>>? Selector { get; init; }

        public Type? SelectorType
        {
            get
            {
                var body = Selector.Body;
                // Unwrap the conversion to object, if there is one.
                if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
                {
                    body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
                }
                return body.Type;
            }
        }

        LambdaExpression? IOrderBySelector<T>.Selector
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Selector == null) return null;
                return (LambdaExpression)this.Selector;
            }
        }
    }
```

The best I could do was interrogate the selector when trying to use it in a Linq query and cast it back to its true type.

part of the method that evaluates the Specification:

```
foreach (IOrderBySelector<Company> thenOrderBy in spec.Filter.ThenBy)
                    {
                        switch (thenOrderBy.SelectorType.FullName)
                        {
                            case "System.String":
                                query = orderdQuery.ThenBy<Company, string>((Expression<Func<Company, string>>)thenOrderBy.Selector);
                                break;
                            case "System.Int32":
                                query = orderdQuery.ThenBy<Company, int>((Expression<Func<Company, int>>)thenOrderBy.Selector);
                                break;
                            case "System.Int64":
                                query = orderdQuery.ThenBy<Company, long>((Expression<Func<Company, long>>)thenOrderBy.Selector);
                                break;
                            case "System.Guid":
                                query = orderdQuery.ThenBy<Company, Guid>((Expression<Func<Company, Guid>>)thenOrderBy.Selector);
                                break;
                            case "System.Decimal":
                                query = orderdQuery.ThenBy<Company, decimal>((Expression<Func<Company, decimal>>)thenOrderBy.Selector);
                                break;
                            default:                                
                                throw new NotImplementedException($"{thenOrderBy.SelectorType.FullName}");
                        }
                    }
```

How would I either rebuild the expression before executing it, or just change the type of the Selector from object back to the appropriate type before executing the query.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by building Expression Tree. I have replaced `Company` with generic parameter `T`

```cs
// just extract expression
var queryExpression = query.Expression;

foreach (var thenOrderBy in spec.Filter.ThenBy)
{
    var orderLambda = thenOrderBy.Selector;

    // here we dynamically create ThenBy
    var queryExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.ThenBy), 
        new [] {typeof(T), orderLambda.ReturnType}, 
        queryExpression, orderLambda);
}

// apply to query
query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(queryExpression);
```